# Unable to restore indexes with mongorestore command in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am unable to restore indexes with mongorestore command while restoring the collection i am getting the collection but i am unable to restore the indexes with it so whats the solution to restore the indexes with collection

This is the command i am using to restore

mongorestore -h ip:portnumber -u name -p passwd -d databasename -c collectionname --authenticationDatabase admin /d/collection.Bson

my Mongodb version is 3.6

Comment: is there a `collection.metadata.json` at the same path location? This is actually required in order to create the indexes, so if it is missing then no indexes will be created.

Comment: yes there are two files in backup with.bson and .json i used to restore with bson whats the procedure to get indexes using json

Comment: There's no procedure just as long as it's actually there and is correctly named. Show what the files are in the directory and look at the content of the related `metadata.json` file that is there. The content is basically the same as what you see from the `getIndexes()` command in the shell, or indeed you can simply create the file with the same content. Show the detail by [editing your question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/208495/edit)